# What does "penalty to/for ..." mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Let's say Team A and Team B have a soccer match. Now the referee says: it's a penalty to Team A. Does it mean Team B Kicks the Penalty kick or Team A kicks it?

And I also saw the phrase "penalty for ...". Does both "penalty for team A" and "penalty to team A" mean the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both *penalty to* and *penalty for* Team A mean that Team A have a penalty. Both are correct, there are just 2 ways of saying it.

If the penalty were for Team B, the referee could say:

> Penalty **against** Team A

Comment: The answer is correct, but I would add that the referee would say "penalty **against**" the offending team (Team B).